# Web service callout from salesforce to .net using SOAP service

Tags: apex, webservices

When i update a picklist value from 'Requested' to 'Approved' then it should invoke a trigger which in turn calls an external web service (.net web application) and pass those data of the updated record along with it and those records should be received by the .net application and saved on sql server database. I am totally new to Salesforce and Web service.

Trigger,

```
trigger AdoptionDetailsTrigger on PCS_Detail__c (after update) {

    List<PCS_Detail__c> adoptionDetail = [Select Id,Tracking_Details__c From PCS_Detail__c Where Id IN :Trigger.new];
    if(adoptionDetail[0].Tracking_Details__c == 'Approved')
    {
    Set<Id> resultIds = (new Map<Id,SObject>(adoptionDetail)).keySet();
    InvokeWebServiceOnAdoptionStatusChange.callWebService(resultIds);
    }
}
```

Apex class future callout,

```
public class InvokeWebServiceOnAdoptionStatusChange {

        @future(callout=true)
        public static void callWebService(Set<Id> resultIds) {
        try {
            String strSobjects = '';
            List<PCS_Detail__c> adoptionDetail = [Select Name__r.Id,Name__r.Name,Name__r.Breed__c,Name__r.Species__c,Name__r.Gender__c From PCS_Detail__c Where Id IN :resultIds];
            strSobjects = strSobjects + ',' + JSON.serialize(adoptionDetail);
            PetInformationDetail.PackageServiceSoap obj = new PetInformationDetail.PackageServiceSoap();
            obj.UpdateDatabase(strSobjects);
        }
        catch(System.AsyncException e) {
            System.debug('Exception' +e);    
        }
    }
}
```

.NET web method,

```
    [WebMethod]
    public void UpdateDatabase(string jsonValues)
    {
        List<PCSDetail> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PCSDetail>>(jsonValues);

        SqlConnection constr = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
        comm.CommandText = "Insert into PetInformation(PetId,PetName,PetBreed,PetSpecies,PetGender) values(@p0,@p1,@p2,@p3,@p4)";
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p0", values[0].Id);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", values[0].Name);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", values[0].Breed);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", values[0].Species);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", values[0].Gender);
        comm.Connection = constr;
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Model,

```
public class PCSDetail
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Breed { get; set; }

    public string Species { get; set; }

    public string Gender { get; set; }
}
```

Apex class generated using the web service WSDL,

```
//Generated by wsdl2apex

public class PetInformationDetail {
    public class UpdateDatabase_element {
        public String jsonValues;
        private String[] jsonValues_type_info = new String[]{'jsonValues','http://tempuri.org/',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://tempuri.org/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'jsonValues'};
    }
    public class UpdateDatabaseResponse_element {
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://tempuri.org/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{};
    }
    public class PackageServiceSoap {
        public String endpoint_x = 'http://localhost:3251/Services/PackageService.asmx';
        public Map<String,String> inputHttpHeaders_x;
        public Map<String,String> outputHttpHeaders_x;
        public String clientCertName_x;
        public String clientCert_x;
        public String clientCertPasswd_x;
        public Integer timeout_x;
        private String[] ns_map_type_info = new String[]{'http://tempuri.org/', 'PetInformationDetail'};
        public void UpdateDatabase(String jsonValues) {
            PetInformationDetail.UpdateDatabase_element request_x = new PetInformationDetail.UpdateDatabase_element();
            request_x.jsonValues = jsonValues;
            PetInformationDetail.UpdateDatabaseResponse_element response_x;
            Map<String, PetInformationDetail.UpdateDatabaseResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, PetInformationDetail.UpdateDatabaseResponse_element>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
              this,
              request_x,
              response_map_x,
              new String[]{endpoint_x,
              'http://tempuri.org/UpdateDatabase',
              'http://tempuri.org/',
              'UpdateDatabase',
              'http://tempuri.org/',
              'UpdateDatabaseResponse',
              'PetInformationDetail.UpdateDatabaseResponse_element'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
        }
    }
}
```

Will this work properly?

Comment: `UpdateDatabase` method accept the `NewPetInformation.ArrayOfPCSDetail` not `List<PCS_Detail__c>`. first create ``NewPetInformation.ArrayOfPCSDetail` and pass into `UpdateDatabase` method.

Comment: @sfdcweb Can you be able to post the sample code.

Comment: Can you add `NewPetInformation` class in your question ?

Comment: @sfdcweb updated the code.

Comment: Ean.. this is not clear to how you will create `NewPetInformation.ArrayOfPCSDetail` with `List<PCS_Detail__c>` this s not clear

Comment: @sfdcweb I will tell you the idea. Can you just modify the code according to it, so that i can generate wsdl again.

Comment: @sfdcweb I need to pass the list of data that i get from query as parameters via web service callout to .NET web method and those data needs to be saved in SQL Server DB.

Comment: Ean... yes I understood you want to pass the `List<PCS_Detail__c>` to webservice. but I can't see a way to related `NewPetInformation.ArrayOfPCSDetail` and `List<PCS_Detail__c>`

Comment: @sfdcweb Can you suggest your way of doing this scenario. If you could post some sample code regarding how we could generally do this it would really be helpful for me.

Comment: @sfdcweb My task is to send the list of data somehow through the web service and get it saved in DB. I need to implement this but i don't know how. Please help me.

Comment: @Ean- 

In this case you need to pass the value like this:

public class InvokeWebServiceOnStatusChange {

    @future(callout=true)
    public static void callWebService(Set<Id> resultIds) {
    try {
        PCSDetail pcs= new PCSDetail();
  pcs.id= 'XYZ';
  pcs.Name='XYZ';
  pcs.Breed= 'XYZ';
  pcs.Species = 'XYZ';
  pcs.Gender = 'XYZ';
        NewPetInformation.PackageServiceSoap obj = new NewPetInformation.PackageServiceSoap();
        obj.UpdateDatabase(pcsDetail);
    }
    catch(System.AsyncException e) {
        System.debug('Exception' +e);    
    }
}

Comment: @NickSFDC I need to get data based on the query. I pass the resultIDs from a trigger and i need to select the data which matches the id in the query.

Answer (score 2):

@Ean,
You need to pass object of PCSDetail not List:
As per my understanding it should be somewhat as below:

```
public class InvokeWebServiceOnStatusChange {

    @future(callout=true)
    public static void callWebService(Set<Id> resultIds) {
    try {
    PCSDetail[] pcsarray= new PCSDetail[]();
    List<PCS_Detail__c> pcsDetailList = [Select Name__r.Id,Name__r.Name,Name__r.Breed__c,Name__r.Species__c,Name__r.Gender__c From PCS_Detail__c Where Id IN :resultIds];
    for(PCS_Detail__c p : pcsDetailList){
        PCSDetail pcs = new PCSDetail();    
            pcs.id= p.Name__r.Id;
            pcs.Name=p.Name__r.Name;
            pcs.Breed= p.Name__r.Breed__c;
            pcs.Species = p.Name__r.Species__c;
            pcs.Gender = p.Name__r.Gender__c;
            pcsarray.add(pcs);     
    }


        NewPetInformation.PackageServiceSoap obj = new NewPetInformation.PackageServiceSoap();
        obj.UpdateDatabase(pcsarray);
    }
    catch(System.AsyncException e) {
        System.debug('Exception' +e);    
    }
}
```

There might be syntax error but , I believe you got the idea.

Comment: What is pcsDetail in the above code. Did you  miss out any line. Also could you tell me whether the web method which i wrote in .NET is correct or not.

Comment: I will try out your idea. Do i need to change the Web method or is it correct?

Comment: You need to pass object of this class in your web service class:

public class PCSDetail
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Breed { get; set; }

    public string Species { get; set; }

    public string Gender { get; set; }
}

I am not sure about .net web method

Comment: Do you mean that i need to modify the WSDLtoApex code and specify the getter,setter in it.

Comment: It says invalid type PCSDetail at line 6. Do you know why?

Comment: I dont know the syntax of declaring array of a class, but we need to pass array of PCSDetail

Comment: I have updated my code but still the error which i mentioned in the question "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [NewPetInformation.PackageServiceSoap].UpdateDatabase(List)." exists.

Comment: NickSFDC ... Just for FYI: - `PCSDetail` class is created at dotnet server end..

Comment: @sfdcweb Is there any way of accomplishing what i need. I have been stuck with this for past 2 days.

Comment: @Ean - Post your original code.

Comment: @NickSFDC Updated my original code.

Comment: @Ean I can't see a way to solve your issue because your one end is in north pole and another in south pole. but problem is there is no road between them..  in your dot net end you are getting `UpdateDatabase(List<PCSDetail> values)`  i.e. `list<PCSDetail>` and salesforce end you are passing `List<PCS_Detail__c>` but in your wsdl class your `UpdateDatabase` class accepting `NewPetInformation.ArrayOfPCSDetail_x` so you need to pass `NewPetInformation.ArrayOfPCSDetail_x` in `obj.UpdateDatabase` method.

Comment: @sfdcweb I understand the issue. I am asking you is there any other alternative way that you can suggest me. Even it needs change of whole code i am ready to do it. How does one normally pass list of values via web callout and accomplish this.?

Comment: @Ean yes so basically the idea is in salesforce end you need create a class like your dot net model `PCSDetail` and pass that list into your weservice method and in your webservice you need to `PackageServiceSoap.UpdateDatabase` method should accept the `List<PCSDetail>` as parameter.. This way you can send the list of values to callout and you can get those values.

Comment: @sfdcweb I am only able to understand it partially. It would be so helpful for me if you could post some sample code regarding what you explained above.

Comment: @sfdcweb can the list of values be converted to json string and passed through web service callout?

Comment: @Ean you can do that convert into JSON and then pass through web service.. and you can deserliaze  that JSON in dot set side. check this post how to create JSON etc https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_Apex_JSON

Comment: @sfdcweb Check my updated question above. Is the code correct?

Comment: @Ean code looks good. Only one request can you please put debug at dot net side before deserliaze and check you are getting the values or not ?

Comment: @sfdcweb Sure. I will do that and get back if i face any issues. Thanks for your support.

Comment: @sfdcweb One small doubt. When using web service callout from Triggers in Salesforce is it possible to get a response back. Since we are calling future callout I think it is not possible. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @Ean yes this is not possible since it is async process. We can't get response back..